# Cascading lookup clolumns in calendar list

Tags: 2013, calendar, cascading

I want create calendar in SharePoint 2013 that the calendar has should be cascading Lookup columns.

How to create cascading Lookup columns in calendar?

Answer (score 0):

You Could Use SP Services. Lets look to this dokumentation : http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=$%28%29.SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns&referringTitle=Documentation

If You have got JQuery instaled id should't be problem :)

Comment: And You should always remeber that in Sharepoint almost everything is a list :)

Comment: Also you can use InfoPath...just do not Google for calendar, but for regular list and you will find lot of examples. SP Services is def. the best solution.